# Filter groups of cells of variable length in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have some groups of cells, indexed by a number and of variable length.

[image: Example input]

The image above shows an example: I have 3 groups, of 2, 1 and 3 items respectively.
I want to create a new sheet that automatically filters all odd-numbered groups. So the output in this case would look like this:

[image: Example output]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=filter( 
  A1:A, 
  isodd( 
    vlookup( 
      row(A1:A), 
      if( isnumber(A1:A), { row(A1:A), A1:A } ), 
      2, 
      true 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```